# How to set window properties by editing the file at runtime?

Tags: c++, mfc, runtime

I'm using **MFC** (superstructure of Win32 API) in C++.

I have a component **Window** and **JSON file**. In JSON file are **height**, **width**, **top**, **left** with **values** (it is not so important).

**What I have now**:
I've a running program and JSON file. If I edit the JSON file and save that, **changes will not change**. Changes takes effect after **when I close and start new program**.

**What I need**:
If I edit the JSON file and save that, change will be **reflected immediately while runtime**.

Any ideas, using pointers or how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an event using FindFirstChangeNotification and then WaitForSingleObject on it. It will signal when a specified event happens to the directory content. You'll then need to reread the and modify your window's position